# Git rebase with forked remote

Tags: git, rebase

There is a main git repo; main-repo; master branch - my-remote.
I forked that to my profile: main-repo; master branch - origin

Added a commit to remote after it was forked.
Added a commit to origin after forking. So now this is one commit ahead and one commit behind.

**Goal**: Rebasing my-remote to origin. In such a way that origin should have commit from my-remote's first and then from origin. I understand that this will create new commits(SHA).

I am cloning from my profile.
`git clone url2`.  - origin

Added remote repo as another remote.
`git remote add my-remote gitRepoToRemote`

I am on my local master branch which is tracking origin.
Trying to rebase.
`git fetch --all`.
`git rebase my-remote/master`.

Got conflicts.
Resolved manually.
then `git add file-with-conflict`.
continue with rebase `git rebase --continue`.
`git push origin HEAD:master`.
Getting error. Why am I getting this error when I resolved conflict before pushing?

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'gitRepoToOrigin'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details
```

Comment: @matt updated question with `git push origin HEAD:master` Question is why am I getting error when I resolved conflict before pushing?

Comment: You're rebasing a local branch. You can't just push as you've changed the history. either pull, or force push. Know that force pushing may cause issues for other users of the branch

Comment: Repos are in the condition that I mentioned (before goal part in Question). How do I apply commit from my-remote to origin? In origin, I first want my-remote's commit and then origin's commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As implied (but not stated) in comments, you will need some kind of forced push.  The reason is not that complicated, but it helps a lot to *draw* the reason, rather than talk about it.  The problem here, to put it in a funny way, is that you have three different repositories all named Bruce, one new commit named Bruce, and one rewrite of that new commit named Bruce.  You now need to tell Bruce to forget about Bruce because Bruce has a new Bruce and Bruce needs to match up with Bruce.

(The above is a bit of overkill, but see also the [had had had had had](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_while_John_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_a_better_effect_on_the_teacher) sentence.)

Instead of calling everyone and everything "Bruce", or trying to give the exact hash ID of each commit—which causes similar (though distinct) problems because *humans* are bad at hash IDs, converting each one to a "Bruce"-like bleep in their heads—let's draw each repository as a series of commits with the commits designated by single uppercase letters.  We start with what you called the "main-repo" at first, then called `my-remote` later when you used `git remote add`:

```
my-remote:

...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

The *name* `master` exists in this repository.  That name stores the hash ID of commit `H` (some big ugly hash ID).  Commit `H`, at the right, is the newest.  It contains:

- a full snapshot of every file, and
- metadata that include the hash ID of earlier commit `G`

so commit `H` links backwards to earlier commit `G`.  Earlier commit `G` has a snapshot of every file (from earlier), of course, plus the hash ID of still-earlier commit `F`.  This repeats all the way back to the beginning of time: this is how Git stores commits.

You then used GitHub's <kbd>fork</kbd> button to make a *copy* of this repository, which we will call `origin`.  This copy has *its own branch names* but *shares the actual commits* with the original repository.<sup>1</sup>  In any case, in this copy over on GitHub, the *name* `master` holds the same hash ID:

```
origin:

...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

You then cloned the GitHub fork to your own computer (we'll call this "laptop", even if it's a desktop or deskside computer, just to give it a memorable but distinct name).  This copied the commits, but the copies are identical to the originals—they have to be; no part of any commit can ever be changed after it's made—and then copied their *branch* names to *remote-tracking names*, so that you had:

```
laptop:

...--F--G--H   <-- origin/master
```

Your `git clone` command then created a new `master` branch in your laptop repository, based on your `-b master` argument, or your lack of any `-b` argument plus the recommendation from GitHub that your Git use the name `master` here:

```
laptop:

...--F--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
```

and finally, on your laptop, your Git ran `git checkout master` to populate a working tree (and Git's *index* though we won't cover this here) from commit `H`, making `master` the *current branch* and commit `H` the *current commit*, on `laptop`:

```
laptop:

...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Whether they *share* the raw underlying commits or copy them isn't really relevant to us.  The fact is that the commits are 100%, bit-for-bit identical.  This means that as long as both `my-remote` and `origin` are stored on the same *physical machine*, they can share the underlying commits.  If they're stored on separate physical machines with separate permanent memory systems (spinning disks, flash, whatever), they'll need to use copies of the raw commit bytes, rather than literally sharing the underlying storage, but we don't care about that.

---

#### Summary so far

As of this time (some time in the past), the contents of all three repositories looks very similar.  The chief—and observable—difference in your laptop repository is that you have `origin/master`, and a working copy of commit `H`.  Other than these differences (important for getting work done, but otherwise irrelevant), all three look like this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

#### Things change over time

Next, though, you made a new commit on your laptop.  We'll call this commit `I`, the next letter after `H`.  So on *laptop* we now have:

```
laptop:

...--F--G--H   <-- origin/master
            \
             I   <-- master (HEAD)
```

Meanwhile, someone sent a new commit to `master` over on GitHub for the `my-remote` repository.  Normally I would call this commit `J` but for no apparent reason, I will call it `K` here.  So *they* have this, which I will draw oddly for no apparent reason either:

```
my-remote:
             K   <-- master
            /
...--F--G--H
```

Note how the repository named `origin` has not changed at all yet.

At this point, you run `git push` on your laptop.  Without worrying too much about exactly which arguments you pass *to* `git push` (if any) here, this winds up sending the one commit that your *laptop* has, that `origin` does not, to `origin`.  So now, on `origin`, you have:

```
origin:

...--F--G--H
            \
             I   <-- master
```

When this push succeeds, your laptop updates its `origin/master`.  That's because your `git push` had your laptop *call* GitHub, over the internet, asking GitHub to connect to repository `origin` (which worked).  Your laptop Git *sent* the data that make up commit `I`, then *asked* GitHub to set *their* `master`, **and they said OK**, so your laptop Git knows that the `origin` Git has its `master` pointing to commit `I`.  So now on `laptop` you have:

```
laptop:

...--F--G--H
            \
             I   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
```

We don't need all these little kinks in the graphs we're drawing here, but I'm using them on purpose.  Note that neither `origin` nor `laptop` know anything about commit `K` yet!  Similarly, `my-remote` has never heard of commit `I`.

#### The fun (?) begins

At this point you start doing something fancy:

> Added remote repo as another remote.
> git remote add my-remote gitRepoToRemote

Your `laptop` Git now knows that another Git, named `my-remote`, *exists*.  It has not yet connected to it.

> ```
> git fetch --all
> ```

Most people misuse `--all`, but here you have used it correctly (congratulations! ).  The `--all` option directs your Git to run `git fetch` against *each remote*.

This was a bit of overkill, because this had your Git call up both `origin` *and* `my-remote`, to see what was new, if anything, in those two repositories.  Nothing was new in `origin`, and nothing *could* be, because you would be the only one updating it.  But that's OK!  When your Git called up the Git called `my-remote`, though, something *was* new: they had commit `K`, which you didn't.

Your Git therefore *obtained* commit `K` *from* `my-remote`, and stuck it in your repository.  Your Git then created—as this was the first contact *with* `my-remote`—a remote-tracking name, `my-remote/origin`.  So now *`laptop`* has:

```
laptop:
             K   <-- my-remote/master
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             I   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
```

(and now you can see why I kept the kink in the graph drawing).

You *could* tell your Git to tell the `origin` Git about commit `K` (sending a copy of `K` *to* `origin` in the process<sup>2</sup).  But, as you can see from this drawing of what things look like on `laptop`, there would be a problem at `origin`: the name `master` can only point to *one* commit.  You can pick *either* commit `I` *or* commit `K`, but not both.  To point to both commits—so that you can find `I` *and* `K`—you need at least *two* names.</sup>

Your repository, on `laptop`, *has* the necessary names: `my-remote/master` points to `K`, and `master` points to `I`.  `origin/master` also points to `I`, so you're free to have your `master` point *anywhere* now: to find commit `K` you can use the name `my-remote/master`, and to find `I` you can use the name `origin/master`.

---

2Since `origin` is a fork of `my-remote`, `origin` could *in theory* be able to *see* commit `K` more directly.  In theory, GitHub *could* arrange for this.  If, how, and when they ever do that is up to them: your Git does not need to know anything about it.  If, how, and when GitHub ever add a *web* mechanism, instead of this somewhat roundabout fetch-and-push-again method, to *introduce* commit `K` into `origin`, is likewise up to GitHub.  As of today, though, you must use the roundabout method.

---

#### Rebase

The rebase command can be summarized this way: *I have some commit(s) that I mostly like, but there's something about those commits that I **don't** like.  I know that I cannot **change** anything about any existing commit, so instead of doing that, I'd like to **copy** the existing commits to new-and-improved ones, in which the things I dislike are changed, and the things I like are retained.*

Let's look again at what we have on `laptop` at this point:

```
laptop:
             K   <-- my-remote/master
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             I   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
```

What we *don't* like about commit `I` are two things:

- it doesn't have the updates from commit `K`, and
- it comes after commit `H`, instead of after commit `K`.

What we *do* like about it are these things:

- it has some changes from commit `H`, and
- it has a carefully crafted, delightfully detailed *commit message* explaining *why* it has these changes.

We would like to retain those two things while making a *new* commit that repairs the two things we *don't* like.  We do this with `git rebase` (which, internally, consists of cherry-picking each of the commits we'd like to copy; there's only one, which is why we just get one new commit).

Without worrying too much about how *that* goes—it sometimes gets messy:

> Got conflicts.  Resolved manually.  then git add file-with-conflict.
> continue with rebase `git rebase --continue`.

but it looks like you did all of this correctly—the *end result* is a new commit:

```
laptop:
               J   <-- master (HEAD)
              /
             K   <-- my-remote/master
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             I   <-- origin/master
```

This *new* commit, `J`, comes after existing commit `K`, and makes the right changes—modified as needed due to the now-resolved conflicts—and carries the right commit message text.  So new commit `J` is the one we want.  It *completely obsoletes* old commit `I`.

**How do we know that `J` replaces `I`, and that `I` is no longer useful?**  The only answer here is that we know it because *we did it*.  *Git* doesn't know or care.  Only *we* know and care.  Our Git, on `laptop`, has our `master` pointing to commit `J` now.  Commit `I` has been abandoned, except for the fact that our `origin/master` can still find it.

#### We now want to tell `origin` to do the same

We can now run:

```
git push origin master
```

or:

```
git push origin HEAD:master
```

to have our Git call up GitHub, have them connect to the `origin` repository, and send them new commit `J`.  This part works—but then we *ask* them to set their `master` to point to commit `J`, and **they say no**.  They say no specifically with the error that says *If I do that, I will abandon some existing commit:*

> ```
>  ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
> ```

This `non-fast-forward` message means *I will lose some commit(s) off my `master`*.

The commit they will lose, in this case, is commit `I`.  Commit `I` is *obsoleted by* commit `J`.  But **they don't know that**.  We have to force them to abandon commit `I`.

The way we do that is to use one of the various forcing options (rather appropriate for Star Wars Day):

```
git push --force origin master
```

or:

```
git push --force-with-lease origin master
```

There is a difference between these, but *in this particular case* (`origin` is "your" fork, controlled by you, not being pushed-to by anyone else) it doesn't really matter.  Both of them work like regular `git push` except that, in the end, instead of sending a polite request: *please, if it's OK and doesn't lose anything, update your `master` to remember commit `J` now*, this kind of push ends with a *command* of the form *update your `master` to point to commit `J`!*  The Git at GitHub will obey this command and leave, in the `origin` repository, this:

```
origin:
               J   <-- master
              /
             K
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             I   ???
```

The Git over at GitHub will eventually—this may take a day or a week or more—run `git gc` and *remove* commit `I`, and we should now start drawing its repository as:

```
origin:

...--F--G--H--K--J   <-- master
```

to simplify it.  We can also start doing that with your laptop, except that we need `my-remote/master` to point to `K`, still, so we get:

```
laptop:
                J   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
               /
...--F--G--H--K   <-- my-remote/master
```

Your laptop Git actually hangs on to commit `I` for quite a while—at least 30 days by default—before throwing it out, but since it's not *visible* (in `git log` output) we don't have to bother drawing it in, at this point.